# Parallel kernel and front end

Tags: front-end, parallelization, kernel

I have a piece of code which looks like this:

```
ParallelTable[

  Monitor[
    Table[
    <code here>
    ,{i,i1,i2];
  ,i];

]
```

so basically a `Table` which I parallelize. Each element of this parallelized table being itself a `Table` which I want to monitor.

I receive this error message:

> FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.

This error originates from the `Monitor[]`. I suspect that because my first `Table` is parallelized, somehow the dynamic cell into which `Monitor[]` will write to is not connected to any Front End or something...

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: What happened when you started a front end?

Comment: from help, it says: `generates a monitor cell that shows the continually updated current value...In a notebook, the monitor cell normally appears directly after the cell in which Monitor[expr,mon] is evaluated` so clearly Monitor requires a frontend. Can't be used in script/batch.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Can you start a front end for each parallel kernel and use `Monitor`?

Comment: In case it is not clear, I have a Front End running for my master kernel. How would I start a Front End for each child kernels ?

Comment: Or rather, each child kernels should use the Front End used by my master kernel...

Comment: @coussin The overhead needed to send things back to the frontend will likely wipe out any advantage of parallelism. If the calculations are very complex and this is not in fact true in your case you could use shared variables.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in the comments by @Nasser, [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html) needs a front end, so it should be outside [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html). It also needs a variable  that acts as a "counter" and that is shared among all the kernels participating in the calculation, for that you can use [`SetSharedVariable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedVariable.html). Therefore, a solution to your question would be:

```
SetSharedVariable[iter]
iter = 0
Monitor[
  ParallelTable[ 
   iter += 1;
   FactorInteger[999999999]
   , {1000}
   ], ProgressIndicator[iter, {0, 1000}]];
```

Its is true that its questionable if the cost of keeping the iteration counter updated makes parallelism  worthwhile, as pointed by @mfvonh. This should be evaluated case by case, and its not impossible that its advantageous. I have found this trick useful at least  once.